# <B1-Motion> binding is unresponsive in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've been working on learning more about the `Canvas()` widget in tkinter, so I decided to build a simple paint app just for practice.

To achieve this, I created a canvas and binded it to `"<B1-Motion>"`, but it becomes unresponsive when I drag the mouse too fast.

Here's a code sample:

```
from tkinter import *


class Paint:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

        self.current_x = None
        self.current_y = None

        self.brush_size = 10
        self.brush_color = "black"

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Creating the canvas
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=1000, height=1000)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # Setting up bindings for the canvas.
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.setup_coords)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drag)

    def setup_coords(self, e):
        # Reset the starting points to the current mouse position
        self.current_x = e.x
        self.current_y = e.y

    def drag(self, e):
        # Create an oval that's size is the same as brush_size
        oval = self.canvas.create_oval(self.current_x, self.current_y, self.current_x+self.brush_size, self.current_y+self.brush_size, fill=self.brush_color)

        # Set the variables values to the current position of the mouse, so that the oval gets drawn correctly on the next call.
        self.current_x = e.x
        self.current_y = e.y


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x1000")
    p = Paint(root)
    p.create_widgets()
    mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here, when I drag the mouse slowly, everything works just fine:
[image]

But as soon as I start dragging fast, the bindings don't get called on time and only a few circles get drawn:
[image]

Am I doing something inefficiently here? Is there any way to fix this problem?

It would be great if anyone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I tried acw1668's suggestion which is drawing lines instead of circles and setting it's width to the brush size:

```
from tkinter import *


class Paint:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

        self.current_x = None
        self.current_y = None

        self.brush_size = 50
        self.brush_color = "black"

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Creating the canvas
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=1000, height=1000)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # Setting up bindings for the canvas.
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.setup_coords)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drag)

    def setup_coords(self, e):
        # Reset the starting points to the current mouse position
        self.current_x = e.x
        self.current_y = e.y

    def drag(self, e):
        # Create an oval that's size is the same as brush_size
        oval = self.canvas.create_line(self.current_x, self.current_y, e.x, e.y, width=self.brush_size, fill=self.brush_color)

        # Set the variables values to the current position of the mouse, so that the oval gets drawn correctly on the next call.
        self.current_x = e.x
        self.current_y = e.y


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x1000")
    p = Paint(root)
    p.create_widgets()
    mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But still, there is some unwanted gap when I increase the brush size:
[image]

Any fixes?

Comment: Better draw lines between points (i.e. between two triggered events) instead of circles.

Comment: @acw1668: I kind of don't get what you're trying to say, but if I draw lines instead of circles, the brush size will be really hard to change. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: You can use the brush size as the `width` of the line.

Comment: @acw1668: Could you please check my updated question and suggest something?

Comment: When creating lines, set `capstyle` to `round`. See e.g. [this canvas tutorial](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html).

Comment: @RolandSmith: Wow! thank you so much, never knew this attribute exists, works totally fine now. If you wish, please write an answer so that I can accept it and close the question, or I can do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For well-connected lines, set the set `capstyle` to `round` when creating lines.

Check out [this canvas tutorial](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html) for more details.

Almost all drawing libraries that I'm familiar with support different line end ("caps") styles, as well as line connection ("joins") styles.

Also note that you can use `create_line` to draw either quadratic [Bézier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Constructing_B%C3%A9zier_curves) splines or cubic splines.